# JQTouch[DataZombie]: Scroller bounces back to top when calendar is in view

Tags: jqtouch

I'm using the [jQTouch-Calendar plugin] (https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQTouch-Calendar) together with [DZ's jQTouch fork](https://github.com/DataZombies/jQTouch) and I'm having trouble with the scroller bouncing back up to the top of the calendar when I try to look at the events of a particular date.
Here's my DOM structure:

```
<div id="events" class="hide_tabbar">
    <div class="toolbar"> ... </div>
    <div class="s-scrollwrapper">
        <div class="content-area">
            <ul id="event-list">
                <!-- Dynamic Content -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the JS code that generates the pane:

```
function buildEvents() {
    console.log("preparing events view");
    var content = "<ul>";
    for (var x = 0; x < events.length; x++) {
        // 2011-05-30 00:00:00.0
        var eventdate = new Date(events[x].eventdate.replace(
            /^(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d) (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d).(\d)$/,
            '$2/$3/$1 $4:$5:$6')
        );

        if (isNaN(eventdate)) continue;

        content += "<li class='arrow'>";
        content += "<time datetime="+ eventdate.format("isoUtcDateTime")+">";
        content += "<a class='event slide plain' href='#event-details' onClick='getEventDetails(\""+events[x].eventrefid+"\")'>";
        content += "<span>"+events[x].eventrefid+"</span>";
        content += "</a></time></li>";
    }

    content += "</ul>";
    $("#event-list").html(content);
    $('#event-list').getCalendar(); //This is the important bit
}
```

It generates the calendar fine but when I have a couple of events on a day (which causes the page to be bigger than the scroller area, the scroller snaps back up to the top when I try to scroll down. Help?